# Pyspark group by and count data with condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to solve some problems using group by functions.
Let me show you my case.
The data I have is like this.

```
| columnA | columnB | columnC | columnD | columnE |
| ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| PersonA | DataOne | 20210101|    1    |    2    |
| PersonA | DataOne | 20210102|    2    |    4    |
| PersonA | DataOne | 20210102|    3    |    4    |
| PersonA | DataTwo | 20201226|    2    |    4    |
| PersonA | DataTwo | 20201226|    7    |    1    |
| PersonA | DataTwo | 20201227|    3    |    2    |
| PersonB | DataOne | 20201225|    1    |    3    |
| PersonB | DataTwo | 20201225|    2    |    4    |
| PersonB | DataTwo | 20201226|    1    |    2    |
```

then, the thing I want to do aggregate columnD, E grouping by column A,B,C but use only
max(columnC).

I did the job like this way code below, But I have been wondering the way simpler and faster.

```
my_df = (The data above)
my_df_max = my_df.groupBy("columnA","columnB").agg(max("columnC").alias("columnC"))
result = my_df\
    .groupBy("columnA","columnB","columnC")\
    .agg(count("columnD").alias("columnD"),sum("columnE").alias("columnE"))\
    .alias("tempA")\
    .join(my_df_max.alias("tempB"), (col("tempA.columnA") == col("tempB.columnA")) & (col("tempA.columnB") == col("tempB.columnB")) & (col("tempA.columnC") == col("tempB.columnC")))\
    .select(col("tempA.columnA"),col("tempA.columnB"), col("tempA.columnC"), col("columnD"), col("columnE"))
```

And the result I expect is way like below.

```
|columnA|columnB|columnC |columnD|columnE|
|-------|-------|--------|-------|-------|
|PersonA|DataOne|20210102|   2   |   8   |
|PersonA|DataTwo|20201227|   1   |   2   |
|PersonB|DataOne|20201225|   1   |   3   |
|PersonB|DataTwo|20201226|   1   |   2   |
```

And If I happen to know the code way and SQL way to realize this job, I would be be very pleased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibly more concise option is to filter your data frame by the maximum value in column C first and then do aggregation, (assuming your spark data frame is named `sdf`):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

sdf.withColumn('rankC', f.expr('dense_rank() over (partition by columnA, columnB order by columnC desc)'))\
    .filter(f.col('rankC') == 1)\
    .groupBy('columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC')\
    .agg(f.count('columnD').alias('columnD'), f.sum('columnE').alias('columnE'))\
    .show()

+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|columnA|columnB| columnC|columnD|columnE|
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|PersonB|DataOne|20201225|      1|      3|
|PersonA|DataOne|20210102|      2|      8|
|PersonB|DataTwo|20201226|      1|      2|
|PersonA|DataTwo|20201227|      1|      2|
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Spark SQL way to do this. You can filter the rows with max columnC using `rank()` over an appropriate window, and then do the group by and aggregation.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')

result = spark.sql("""
    SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC, count(columnD) columnD, sum(columnE) columnE 
    FROM (
        SELECT *, rank() over(partition by columnA, columnB order by columnC desc) r 
        FROM df
    )
    WHERE r = 1
    GROUP BY columnA, columnB, columnC
""")

result.show()
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|columnA|columnB| columnC|columnD|columnE|
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|PersonB|DataOne|20201225|      1|      3|
|PersonA|DataOne|20210102|      2|      8|
|PersonB|DataTwo|20201226|      1|      2|
|PersonA|DataTwo|20201227|      1|      2|
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```